# Creating a pure component by constant - javascript or by React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, it is quite often used creating components without any state, just like function,

e.g.

```
const Count = () => {
    return(
        ...some tags...
    )
}
```

In this case, I see some cases that components with states are defined by extending components defined like above,

e.g.

```
class CounterContainer extends Count{
    .... some codes
}
```

In my opinion, 'Count' component is not defined with typical class definition in javascript, but like a function.

But I can't tell it for sure... Is this only possible in React or generally ok in Javascript?

Comment: Both syntaxes are correct depending on your needs : https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html. The class component will just handle its state by itself, as you will see in the next page of the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why components are designed like that in React is because it makes components simpler when you don't need to handle state and so you don't need a lot of the boilerplate seen in traditional react classes with the constructor, render method, extends Component and so on. So you can have your simple, or as they're often referred to - *dumb* stateless components versus more complex stateful components.

Both are still valid Javascript. It's just a preference on how to write your code.